# Mirror two different devices via usb

Tags: ios, wifi, airplay, quicktime

I am trying to do two demos running on two devices.  The goal would be to plug an external monitor into my computer and have one display show one device, and the other show the other device.

I would use Reflect 2, but it only does wifi, or personal hotspot
I would use quicktime but it only supports one device at a time.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused as to which devices you want doing what. Perhaps some sort of basic diagram could help?

Comment: @JMY1000 I just added a diagram, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [It's now quite easy to do so using Quicktime.](https://medium.com/@patrickswong/how-to-mirror-your-iphone-with-a-lightning-cable-using-quicktime-in-os-x-yosemite-ace3f40ef483#.s1bbapu0b)

Connect both phones to the computer using a USB -> Lightning cable.

Open QuickTime Player.

Choose File -> New Movie Recording twice.

[image]

Choose a given phone to mirror for each of the windows.

[image]

Move the windows around as you see fit!

Comment: Unfortunately I can only get quicktime to do one.  Even with two instances going if you have one movie recording going it wont let you start another.  And if you do manage to get it to where you have two video recordings, when you set the sources you get an error.

Comment: @J.Doe Hmm, wasn't aware of that. Duly noted.

Comment: Yeah it is a pretty stupid limitation, if third party software can handle doing two devices over wifi, it would figure that a wired connection of two devices wouldnt be a hassle.